# Can't install any Nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, graphics

When i run:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00002520sv00001025sd00001547bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation  
model    : GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q]  
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-open - third-party non-free recommended  
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-server - distro non-free  
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free  
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free  
driver   : nvidia-driver-515 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-open - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525 - third-party non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

When i install the recommended driver (nvidia-driver-525-open), i get a black screen.

When i install nvidia-driver-515 (or any below version) i get stuck at login screen (keyboard, mouse, nothing is working… even ctrl+alt+f1 to open another tty).

This is the bug report log for the nvidia-driver-525:
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/uploads/short-url/hu0foxXT3RfYSgvYz9Ei2dMtDdZ.log

Laptop: Acer Predator Helios 300 PH315-54-760S Gaming Laptop
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060
Kernel: 5.15.0-57-generic
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Please help me!

Comment: What about if you just install the non-open driver `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525`?  But also make sure to disable Secure Boot in the BIOS when installing these drivers.

Comment: yes i tried it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled secure boot, installed the latest kernel, reinstalled gdm3 gnome-shell ubuntu-desktop.

Also it seems that it was missing the package xserver-xorg-input-all.

And finally i reinstalled nvidia-driver-525

Works great now :)